# Can I get a preview window in Sublime2?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

I'm new to coding and I'm coding with Sublime. I currently use 3 windows, 1 for HTML, 1 for my css and the final for my JavaScript. I know i can use a 4th so is it possible to use this window as a preview window for what I've typed?

It seems it would be more beneficial to me seeing the changes instead of having to saving all 3 files then open in browser.

Hope you can help!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Sublime is not a web browser, so no, you can't do this. However, you may want to check out the [`LiveReload`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload) plugin, available via Package Control. Along with the corresponding browser plugin, it allows you to have a live preview of the code you're working with.